# How to make getBBox ignore clipped svg elements

Tags: javascript, html, svg, bounding-box

I have a javascript/nw.js project with an svg (referred below as svg-canvas) element that serves as a drawing canvas and inside it I have another movable svg element (referred below as svg-encapsulate) designed to encapsulate a dynamic collection of objects in a constrained space and whose size is therefore clipped using width and height properties. That way elements drawn inside that spill over its edges are clipped, so as not to appear to be spilling outside of the element. However, when I do getBBox on the svg-canvas, the BBox returns size that also includes clipped (invisible) elements inside the svg-encapsulate, which in turn triggers scrollbars for the entire element even when visually (from the perspective what user sees) everything fits. Is there a way to instruct getBBox to ignore clipped elements of the svg-encapsulate, so that one can maintain correct scrollbar behavior? Please note since svg-encapsulate can be resized, moved, and populated with various objects by a user, hardcoded margins and workarounds will not work in this case. Thanks!

Comment: remove the clipped element, get the bounding box of the rest, add the clipped element back in again.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Is that the best/only option?

Comment: Well maybe you could put everything except the clipped element in a group and get the group's bounding box but that might not work with your rendering order.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. I actually did what you suggested first and that seems to work just fine. Does hiding and showing objects like this (svg display block to display none and back) have a big hit on performance? Does not look like it from the quick tests so far. Just curious if this may be an issue down the road performance-wise.